# How to let Cloud server to access a Licensing dongle?

Tags: usb, cloud, licensing, citrix

In our company, we use licensing USB dongle to control the license management. This dongle typically is plugged in to a server computer on the network.
Now some user asked if we have a solution to use on a cloud based server(Citrix Server), where it is no possible to attach the dongle there.
does anyone have experience to handle this situation?

Comment: Yep, you get a "dongle server". Works like a Microsoft license server, but for dongles.

Comment: thanks. can we install our own service program on the cloud server, and instruct it to look for the dongle on the dongle server or on any other network computer?

Answer (score 4):

Few ideas:

- Check with the people who wrote the software the dongle came with for a compatible solution (that doesn't require a physical dongle).
- If you can get at the Citrix server itself you may be able to use USB pass-through to your software's VM.
- Check out Digi's "[USBAnywhere](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb)" USB over IP network devices. Either discuss implementing one with your cloud provider or, depending on your scenario and how the dongle works, perhaps deploy it on the local LAN.

Comment: thanks. this is the way we do at the moment: 1. install a service program on the server; 2. plug in the dongle on the server; 3. start the service. the service will communicate with the dongle to grant licence to the user. a few files will be created on the server which will allow user to access and communicate. We use Matrix dongle from MetrixLock.de